# How to create a list of the autocomplete <li> elements when parent <ul> element contains the attribute style="display: none;" through Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, display, autosuggest

I'm using Java selenium to create a automation project. Now in our web app, there is address input box and has autocomplete feature. The problem is after input a partial address, we need click one of the option from the list. Here is the html:
[image: hrml ul list]

Now I have tried to get the list. But failed:

```
WebElement autoCompelet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/ul[1]"));
List<WebElement> options = autoCompelet.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
logger.debug(options.size());
for (WebElement option1 : options) {
    logger.debug(option1);
}
```

I can print out , but

list is empty.
I've also tried to use wait method like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/ul[1]/li[1]")));
```

Unfortunately, none of them works. Is anyone has any idea on this? Any input is appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`By.className("li")` is invalid,the value should be the class name,need to use `By.tagName("li")` instead.

Also you can change your xpath to get `ul` by class and then get `li` directly

```
WebElement autoCompelet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='af_list']"));
List<WebElement> options = autoCompelet.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
logger.debug(options.size());
for (WebElement option1 : options) {
    logger.debug(option1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried tagName, it wasn’t work. Not sure what is the difference between tagName and Name

Comment: @ShiTim just use `name`,why do you want to use `tagName`?

Comment: It should be `tagName` and not `name`. `name` can be used to identify an element according to its `name` attribute if it has one. This attribute is used to uniquely identify an input element within HTML form, to send data to the server using a POST request.

Comment: Got it fix by using className. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below.

```
    //wait is added in order to check the presence of autocomplete suggestion 
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("af_list")));

    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='af_list']/li"));
    logger.debug(options.size());
    for (WebElement option1 : options) {
        logger.debug(option1.getText());
    }
```

Note: I have assumed `af_list` class name is used only in the autocomplete.If it is used in other section as well, then please share the full html detail

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this , after having all the `<li>` elements in a **list**, you can easily get the text of each web element by using `getText()` method which is available in **selenium** **Java** **binding**.

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.af_list li"));
 System.out.println(options.size());
 logger.debug(options.size());
 for(WebElement options1 : options)
  {
    logger.debug(options1.getText());
   }
```

Note that it is always a good practice to use **css** **selector** over **xpath**.

You may want to introduce webDriverWait for your scenario. That would explicitly wait for all `<li>` elements to be present/available in list.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar feature in our web application. In this case, you can use `sendKeys()` method with `Keys.DOWN` to literally go to that element and then `Keys.ENTER` to select it. Normally once you `sendKeys()` part of the text, the others start populating below, so you basically type to an extent until which just the first option in the populated **dropdown** texts is the one which you want. Then do `sendKeys(Keys.DOWN)` followed by `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared, the desired elements i.e. the `<li>` tags are within a `<ul>` tag which is having the attribute **style="display: none;"**. So to access the `<li>` tags you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement autoCompelet = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='af_list']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", autoCompelet);
List<WebElement> options = autoCompelet.findElements(By.xpath("./li[@class='af_item']"));
for (WebElement option1 : options) {
    System.out.println(option1.getText());
}
```